# Проблемы с импортом из maven local

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Я установил джарник с нужной мне библиотекой в maven local следующей командой:

```
mvn install:install-file 
-Dfile=/home/IdeaProjects/webstruct/build/libs/webstruct-0.0.2.jar 
-DgroupId=ru.xpendence 
-DartifactId=webstruct 
-Dversion=0.0.2 
-Dpackaging=jar 
-DgeneratePom=true
```

Всё вроде ок, в .m2 библиотека появилась. Далее я добавил зависимость в `build.gradle`:

```
compile group: 'ru.xpendence', name: 'webstruct',version: '0.0.2'
```

Но когда я пытаюсь применить классы из библиотеки, например, унаследоваться от абстрактных классов, нужный класс появляется в импорте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я его импортирую, импорт не появляется, класс пытается импортироваться следующим образом, причём, как мы видим, распознать пакет IDEA не может:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, библиотека есть в зависимостях:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, в чём проблема? Джарник собирал через build.

Comment: А что говорит градл, если попробовать скомпилировать проект через него, а не используя идее ?

Comment: говорит error: package ru.xpendence.webstruct.entity does not exist

Comment: Вероятно что проблема с собранным жарником. Попробуйте распаковать собранный жар и посмотреть, что у него внутри.

Comment: Внутри у него всё то же, что и ожидалось.

Comment: Кстати, такой вопрос. При сборке gradle пихает в библиотеку spring. Как сделать так, чтобы зависимости библиотеки не добавлялись в джарник, а подтягивались при добавлении библиотеки?

Comment: Попробуйте scope "compileOnly".